# Upload multiple files & create zip

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, filepath, dotnetzip

I managed to upload two kinds of files successfully & store the respective filepaths on the database. Now,I'd also like to create a zip with both files attached to it.

*I referenced the codes to this particular webpage regarding zip files & file uploads
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/5089e0/how-to-create-zip-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp/*

Upon clicking the submit button, a File Not Found exception is thrown.
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Ionic.Zip.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: C:\Users\seldarine\Desktop\Proj\PP_PJ\PP_Project\SFiles\Submissions\blueteam\MyCodesF.zip

The exception is thrown at this particular line - **objZip.Save(Path.Combine(serverFilePath,zipName));**

Here are a portion of my codes :

```
  protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = "";
        string pp, vv,zip;
        string extPp, extVv;

        if (f_slide.HasFile && f_video.HasFile)
        {
            //Get file name & extensions
            pp = Path.GetFileName(f_slide.PostedFile.FileName);
            extPp = Path.GetExtension(pp);
            vv = Path.GetFileName(f_video.PostedFile.FileName);
            extVv = Path.GetExtension(vv);

            string user = Session["userid"].ToString();
            //where zip name is named after the username (current user)  logged in
            string zipName = user + ".zip";

            //To save to folders
            string filePath = "SFiles/Submissions/" + user + "/";
            string serverFilePath = Server.MapPath(filePath);

            //If directory does not exist
            if (!Directory.Exists(serverFilePath))
            { // if it doesn't exist, create
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(serverFilePath);
            }

            //****To create zip file*****
            using(ZipFile objZip = new ZipFile())
            {
                string zipSlidePath = Path.Combine(serverFilePath,pp);
                string zipVideoPath = Path.Combine(serverFilePath,vv);
                objZip.AddFile(zipSlidePath);
                objZip.AddFile(zipVideoPath);
                ***objZip.Save(Path.Combine(serverFilePath,zipName));***
            }

            //Store files
            f_slides.SaveAs(Path.Combine(serverFilePath, pp));
            f_video.SaveAs(Path.Combine(serverFilePath, vv));

            .....
```

Comment: Are your posted files really stored here: "SFiles/Submissions/" + user + "/" ?

Comment: Yes the files are stored there. I feel there's something wrong with the syntax, at the line where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another line above the crashing one and see if you can debug it and what result you get:

```
var savePath = Path.Combine(serverFilePath,zipName +".zip");
```

You might also want to try changing the savePath variable to something like c:\temp\test.zip and see if that works.

```
var savePath = "c:\\temp\\test.zip";
```

Comment: Same exception results. Exception:Thrown: (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)

Comment: Can you post the entire text of the exception please?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user under which the server is running has write access to that folder (serverFilePath).